# Prawn bounding box stroke with auto height

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawn

```
bounding_box([(bounds.left + 5), bounds.top - 130], width: 750) do
  font_size(10)
  text_box "#{@post.description}", inline_format: :true, :at => [bounds.left + 10, bounds.top - 10]

  stroke do
    rectangle [0, 0],  760, :height => :auto  # ===> I need this height auto
  end
end
```

I am using prawn to generate pdf in my rails app. Above is my code. I need to show the description in a rectangle. When the description is very large, it goes out of the rectangle. Rectangle height do not automatically increase. How can I do that? Also how to add page automatically when description do not fit in single page?

Answer (score 1):

After your `text_box`, replace the `stroke` block with this:

```
stroke_bounds
```

That will draw a rectangle around the bounding box, however tall it is, as long as it doesn't cross a page boundary.